# What is the word or phrase for the revelation of finding a word for a concept you already knew but did not have the word for?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This has recently happened. I discovered Object Orientated CSS. I had the concept for a long time but had never had a title for the concept. Discovering this was a joy for me.

**Is there a word or phrase that encapsulates that feeling?**

Another example I have is being told about the German word *schadenfreude* many years ago. Finding a word for that concept was a great feeling.

Comment: "[***Eureka***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_(word))!"

Comment: [Epiphany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_(feeling))?

Comment: I say this particular feeling *deserves* a dedicated name. Let's call it ... "*nomenGLADture*" :)

Comment: [Par ma foi ! il y a plus de quarante ans que je dis de la prose sans que j'en susse rien, et je vous suis le plus obligé du monde de m'avoir appris cela.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bourgeois_gentilhomme)

Comment: I also thought Eureka and Epiphany, however (and I'm probably being picky here) they feel more for when you come up with the idea yourself, rather than finding the word. @DanBron I like this. "Finding that word gave me a good feeling of nomengladture". I think the answer is: there is no word that currently exists!

Comment: *Serendipity/Serendipitous joy*

Comment: *So that’s what it’s called!’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not specific to finding a word, such an experience can be called:

- *an epiphany* (experience of sudden and striking realization)
- *a serendipity* (instance of finding valuable or agreeable things not sought for)
- or *an Aha-Erlebnis* (German for aha-experience).

Following Archimedes, the interjection to celebrate such a discovery is *eureka* (ancient Greek for “I have found it”).

Let’s make this specific to finding a word:

- *a vocabularic epiphany*
- *a terminologic serendipity*
- *a vernacular epiphany* (specific to the native language or dialect, especially in contrast to the lingua franca)

The perfectly appropriate word or phrase itself is often called a *mot juste* (French for “right word”).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think such a word exists. If you want a German one, I could suggest 'Wortentdeckungsfreude', but I just made that up.